# Getting and downloading the last version of Blender used to save file

Tags: versions

Getting and downloading the last version of Blender used to save file.

I looked at:
[Do .blend files store information on which version of Blender they were created in?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/624/do-blend-files-store-information-on-which-version-of-blender-they-were-created)

Used a hex editor:
[image: img1]

I also used the linux command.

```
file --uncompress candle\ L\ tube.blend 
candle L tube.blend: Blender3D, saved as 64-bits little endian with version 3.03
```

**But where can I find the old version of Blender 3.03 to download**?

I tried https://builder.blender.org/download/daily/archive/

Comment: if it is not in the archive, i think the only chance you have is to compile it yourself from github

Comment: Here's the archive of V3.xx : https://download.blender.org/release/Blender3.0/ However there doesn't seem to exist a V3.03

Comment: Any particular reason why you want a specific sub-version? If you can explain why you need a particular version we may be able to help.

Comment: @JohnEason Yes the file keeps crashing along with the blend1 file in the current 3.5 version so I want to go back to the last version that it successfully saved to see if it opens up in that version of blender

Comment: It certainly shouldn't crash because newer Blender versions should always be able to open earlier version files even if things don't always work as you expect. I'd suggest you try downloading Blender 3.3.5 from [here](https://www.blender.org/download/releases/3-3/) which is the current LTS (Long Term Support) version and try that.

Comment: @JohnEason thanks the 3.3.5 version allowed the file to open.  Not sure why it crashes Blender 3.5,  my guess is it has to deal with some geometry node changes.  But at-least I can open it and use it Thanks!

Comment: You'd usually expect a node to be shown in red in the editor if it's not compatible with the Blender version. It certainly shouldn't crash Blender! I'd be inclined to report it as a bug via Help > Report a Bug in Blender explaining exactly which version of Blender does and doesn't crash and including the Blend file with your report.

Comment: @JohnEason  I plan to I just want to narrow it down a little for them by at-least trying to find which node or nodes is causing the crash.

Comment: Fair enough but that's usually the developers job especially in such a recent Blender version.

Comment: I have found that they changed something with the way they are showing the Blender version with 3.x. In the image above, that is Blender 3.3.x, not 3.03. If you look at anything created or saved with Blender 3.x, they all show v30x, e.g., 3.5 is v305.

Comment: @JohnEason I made a bug report and they have verified it and are looking at it.   https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/106982

Comment: Good to know! Hopefully it can be corrected before 3.5.1 is released.